# Mutex.WaitOne() always true

Tags: c#, .net, mutex, semaphore

I have a thread that execute the static Method GetTasksToHandle that has mutex inside it that only one application can get a task at each time.
However the mutex always return true

Please assist me, what am I doing wrong?

```cs
public static class BLStaticTask 
{
    private static Mutex TasksMut = new Mutex(); 

    public static List<Tasks> GetTasksToHandle()
    {
        try
        {
            if (TasksMut.WaitOne())
            {
                using (DBContext db = new DBContext ())
                {
                    return db.prGetTasksToHandle().ToList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                TasksMut.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried everything, nothing works. Mutex.waitone always true

Answer (score 4):

That's by design. Let's look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-6.0#system-threading-waithandle-waitone):

> Returns `true` if the current instance receives a signal.  If the
> current instance is never signaled, `WaitOne()` never returns.

It will never return `false`, it will simply block until it is available.

If you want to wait up to a certain amount of time, you can try the `WaitOne` overload that takes a timeout:

```
if (TasksMut.WaitOne(1000)) // wait up to 1000 milliseconds
{
    // mutex held
}
else
{
    // mutex couldn't be taken before timeout
}
```

That one will return `false` if the timeout elapses before the mutex is free.